# Java , read text file continuously is not working

Tags: java

i have used the following method to read lines from a TEXTFILE , whenver it is updated or new lines inserted to the textfile i must print that new line

searching inside this site give me the idea but it is not working

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("filename.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
while (true) {
    String line = reader.readLine();
    if (line != null) {
        // Use line
    }
    else {
        thread.sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Note :  i need to capture the new lines that appended to the Text file while the loop is running , i hope that it is clear to you

Comment: Do you mean that it changes while the while loop is running?

Comment: Infinite loop. Beware

Comment: How do you update the file?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking to kind of do a Unix tail -f.  Is that right?

Comment: i mean , the text file now have new lines . so i need to capture these new lines while i am in the loop

Comment: maybe use watchservice in java to listen change in file

Comment: Just tried on my machine. Your code seems doing what you want.
That's why I'm asking how do u update your file

Comment: @Ming i just open/edit the text file and insert new lines

Comment: Depends on which editor your are using. I tried echo "NEW CONTENT" >> filename.txt .And your code do print the new content.
I'm wondering your file is deleted and replaced during editing.

Comment: @Ming using Echo is working with me , but why when i edit the file using gedit my app will not catch the changes ! why ?

Comment: Too long to put in comment. Added as an answer :)

Comment: What if you have read all 7 lines of your file and waiting for a new line, and then someone changes character 3 of line 2 of your file?

Comment: Only the newly added length will be print according his implementation. 
Replace content won't trigger anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Tailer implements Runnable {
    private File file;
    private int runEvery;
    private long lastPosition = 0;
    private boolean run = true;

    public Tailer(String inputFile, int interval) {
        file = new File(inputFile);
        this.runEvery = interval;
    }

    public void stop() {
        run = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            while(run) {
                Thread.sleep(runEvery);
                long fileLength = file.length();
                if(fileLength > lastPosition) { 
                    RandomAccessFile fh = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                    fh.seek(lastPosition);

                    byte c;
                    while((c = (byte)fh.read()) != -1) {
                        System.out.print((char)c);
                    }
                    lastPosition = fh.getFilePointer();
                    fh.close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            stop();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
        Tailer tailer = new Tailer("test.log", 1000);
        executor.execute(tailer);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks , it is worked for me , but how i change it to read the whole line not byte per byte

Comment: actually , it does not work as expected , when i need to read it line by line could you please help me ?

Comment: Why did you need to read exactly lines? What does mean "does not work as expected"?

Comment: my requirement is to capture each line and do some process on that line so i need to check each line alone ..not as expected means that the pointer is not moving correctly to the next line , it drops the first char on the line

Comment: Strangely, I can not reproduce it. Everything works.

Comment: if i use your sample it works great but as i told you it produce char by char , but i need it to be line by line so i change the code to use readline() instead of read() , and it some time fail to give me the line from the started chararcter , it shift one letter

Comment: I tried
`String line;
while((line = fh.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}`
and it's work. Are you sure you don't lose the first character in a different place?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the apache commons class "org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer".

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/input/Tailer.html

```
  TailerListener listener = new MyTailerListener();
  Tailer tailer = new Tailer(file, listener, delay);

  // simple executor impl. for demo purposes
  Executor executor = new Executor() {
      public void execute(Runnable command) {
          command.run();
       }
  };

  executor.execute(tailer);
```

For example

```
class MyTailerListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {
public void handle(String line) {
  System.out.println(line);
}
}
TailerListener listener = new MyTailerListener();
Tailer tailer = Tailer.create(file, listener, 10000);
tailer.stop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Linux,

File are actually inode. Your old file probably got deleted while saving using gedit. For eg:

At first, you have filename.txt with inode number 10. And the java is reading it. But when you save edit with gedit. The file probably get replace by 
filename.txt with inode number 11. But the Java application is still reading the inode 10. So the application won't able to see any change. 
You can try use "ls -i" to find out the inode number of your file. See if it changed after edit.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that your file isn't saving when the changes are made so your code never registers any new lines. Also, it probably still has the original file open while you're in the loop so it never opens the new file with the changes either. Try putting the open file in the while loop and make sure to close the file too.